# User Experience Designer / Interaction Designer - Who Am I?

Tags: terminology

I have been into User Experience area since last 1.5 Years. Still a newbie here. UX is a fresh concept to my organization. And I & Organization are working together to make UX an integral part of each Product Design/Development.

Going ahead my Organization wants me to name my current position. I am confused here.

@Current Job, my responsibilities are  -

- Get requirements by client or Discuss features on the table
- Depending upon the requirements/features I create balsamiq wire-frames. I represent my wireframes to client and a pilot team of 3-4 members.
- Once brainstorming is done on wireframes and agreed by everyone, I create High Fidelity Mockups with Adobe FireWorks.
- Mockups are then hosted onto a collaborative environment like "Invisionapps/uxpin" where prototype are tested by team members & client.
- If everything looks good - I hand over mockup image to UI team, which creates HTML/CSS for mockups. Which then goes to the Development team. During both HTML & Development process I sit with them and make sure everything is designed & developed as discussed & expected.
- Post development phase I do some Usability Testing too.

These are my Job Responsibilities. I looked at [this](http://www.onwardsearch.com/UX-Career-Guide/UX-Career-Guide-Infographic.pdf) too, But Can't understand **WHO AM I?** Do you have an answer?

Comment: It might help to think about who do you consider yourself to be working for, with, or on behalf of? Your organization, your clients, or your users.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this? [What is User Experience (UX)?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/what-is-user-experience-ux?rq=1).

I would expect your responsibilities to be part of many UX and interaction designers' activities. There is a lot of overlap. A good interaction designer puts ideas about user experience into the interaction. A UX designer might design (part of) the interaction.

However, a UX designer's primary concern is with the holistic experience of the product. A concern that lives on a more abstract and metaphorical level than the primary concern of the interaction designer who's primary job it is to design the interaction with the product. While you might say the interaction *is* the product (to the user anyway and especially in software), the interaction is always only a part of the experience.